# form-data file upload + array of object

Tags: java, spring, rest, file-upload, postman

I want to push data inside a form to my Spring REST api. The handler method looks as follows:

```
@PostMapping
public RepresentationModel<?> handleFileUpload(
    @RequestParam(value = "file") MultipartFile file,
    @RequestParam(value = "description", required = false) String description,
    @RequestParam(value = "public") Boolean publicAccessible,
    @RequestParam(value = "access") @Valid List<SomeObject> access,
    Authentication authentication) {

        ....
}
```

[image: postman]

this gave me:

[image: response postman]

But I need a way to wrap a complex Object into my array.

This is the only thing I came up with so far.
How do I have to shape my request in Postman to satisfy my controller? The problem is the access attribute. Spring complains all the time access parameter is not present or access parameter is not of type List.
In Json my request should look like this:

```
"public": "true",
"description": "Bachelor Dokument",
"access": [
  {
    "someAttribute": "something",
    "someAttribute2": "something"
  },
  {
    "someAttribute": "something2",
    "someAttribute2": "something2"
  }
]

...

/*Content of uarttest.py*/
```

I need the form-data for uploading files I figured. Or do I do something wrong here?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to just use one `access` variable in your Postman request with the desired `JSON` as value:

[image]

Of course, you need to specify the `Content-Type` as `application/json` of the `access` field.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this does not work for me.
I get the following: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkT4J.png
I think postman escapes the payload of the field as a String.

Comment: remove Valid annotation before List in your request mapping. List is not a JavBean, so Valid is useless there.